# Mobile Safari on iOS 11 doesn't show "Save to Files app" option when viewing an MP4

Tags: metadata, ios11, file-type

I understand this is a broad question, but I've googled as much as possible and couldn't find a solution (or discussion) anywhere.

When viewing an MP4 directly in Mobile Safari, if you open then sharing sheet at the bottom, we should be able to save it to the Camera Roll or at least to the Files app, right?

Is it a metadata issue, requiring the file to have a specific mime-type?

Here's an example MP4 URL that i'be been trying:
http://reindeerreadyimages.s3.amazonaws.com/NcuAAwekdT0Q.mp4

Any idea what to do see the save/download option?

Here's what I see currently in the action sheet:
[image]

Many thanks for your help in advance